# How to access an ssh server that can't accept incoming connections

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall

The server is current running bitvise SSH (I can readily switch to another solution), it is behind a firewall that blocks incoming connections (I can't open it because of reasons).

I have a computer outside of the network which is contacted periodically.

So I have a connection right?

So how can I start a SSH session utilizing the connection?

Comment: Please add more detail.  "A connection" is too vague to be useful.

Comment: Paul i was referring to Ssh connection in the entire context..  But i used a connection implying i cant create connection of any kind from the client to server...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am interpreting your problem correctly:

- S = server behind firewall
- C = client outside firewall and cannot reach S on port 22 directly.

... but S can `ssh` **to** C, you could have S setup a reverse port forward by something like this:

```
server% ssh -fR 8822:localhost:22 client
```

then, later, you can connect from the client to the server by connecting to the local port on the client which is forwarding traffic to the server.

```
client% ssh localhost -p 8822
```

Comment: You are correct but C can't reach  S at any port, unless S has started a connection...  That's why i was thinking of a keep alive server K which C will keep connecting, S will notify K when it needs a ssh sesion then K will then notify C next time it connects... The C will allow an ssh season on S by connecting to it directly or through K