# SSH tunneling and port forwarding to connect with MySQL behind ssh proxy

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy, mysql-workbench

I have a mysql running in a machine(C) behind an SSH proxy machine (B). I want to connect to mysql on C on port 3306 using mysql workbench in my local computer(A). Machine B is accessible by machine A via ssh for a user abc with a private key. machine C is accessible to machine B via ssh for user root using the same private key (The key has to be forwarded which usually happens when I do A- ssh -> B - ssh -> C)

What should be my tunneling strategy? Do I need to use socks proxy?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to go from A to C via ssh is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I want to reach C from A

Answer (score 1):

Although not an exact match, here are a couple of other closely related questions:

1. [how to access an ssh server that cant accept incoming connections](https://superuser.com/questions/1062061/how-to-access-an-ssh-server-that-cant-accept-incoming-connections)
2. [establishing an ssh connection between machines behind firewalls](https://superuser.com/questions/965073/establishing-an-ssh-connection-between-machines-behind-firewalls)

To solve your specific problem, I would add the following to your `.ssh/config` file on "A":

```
Host B
  User abc
  ForwardAgent yes

Host C
  User root
  LocalForward 3306:localhost:3306
  ProxyCommand ssh -A B -p 22 -W %h:%p
  #ProxyCommand ssh -A B -p 22 nc %h %p
```

With that in place, you should be able to use `ssh C` to:

- get a shell on C, hopping through B, and
- establish a local (to host A) port forward for your mysql workbench.

Once the connection is established, you can point your local (on A) mysql workbench at localhost:3306.  If you have some other mysql instance running locally on A, choose a different port in the `LocalForward` configuration option and connect to that.

Note that there are two options for the ProxyCommand to jump through B to get to C. The alternative uses `nc` instead of the `-W` option to `ssh`, since the `-W` option wasn't addded unitl ssh version 5.3 (IIRC).

You don't need to use a SOCKS proxy.